# calculate complexity of LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, algorithm-analysis, big-o

I have an `ArrayList<LinkedHashSet<String>> setOfStrings` for example this arraylist internally is composed like:

```
positionX[hello,car,three,hotel,beach]
positionY[.....]
...
```

I want to find car inside this data-structure, so I did it

```
for (Iterator<LinkedHashSet<String>> iterator = setOfStrings.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) { 
    LinkedHashSet<String> subSet = iterator.next();
    if (subSet.contains("hotel"))
        System.out.println("found");
}
```

The for iterate over the entire `arrayList` and the complexity in the worst-case is O(n), but I'm confused on the complexity of the method `contains()` of set. In according of `javadocs` this method is executed in **constant time**, but I've heard that in certain cases the complexity might become `O(n)`. Saying that, I'm not sure about the complexity of this snippet algorithm.

Can someone provide me an explanation of that?

Comment: What do you mean with complexity? Is it o-complexity http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity? Or do you mean average amortized time http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amortized_analysis?

Comment: i mean o-complexity.

Comment: The problem is that hashtable-based collections have average cases and worst cases http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table.

Comment: @EugenePodskal i know, in this case the search of the string using contains is o(n) or it run in constant time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LinkedHashSet`, for the intents and purposes of being accessed using `contains` is simply a hash set.  It uses the return from `hashCode` of the objects inserted in it to determine the position to place it in in the hash set.  If you have a collision, then it will then check the next element.  If that is occupied, it will then check the one after that, and so forth.  Therefore, for hash sets with relatively small capacity or types which do not return distinguishable `hashCode` values, you will see up to `O(n)` complexity for insertion or checking the esistence of an item in the hash set.  However most times you don't see collisions and so in most cases it will be `O(1)`.

Combine this with a `O(n)` operation on all entires in your `ArrayList`, and you end up with `O(n)*O(1)` complexity on average or `O(n)`.  However if the `hashCode()` does not properly distinguish values or if the capacity is small for the `LinkedHashSet`, you may see up to `O(n*m)` complexity (`O(n)*O(m)`) where n is the number of elements in your `ArrayList` and m being the number of elements on average in each `LinkedHashSet`.

Hope that answers your question!

Comment: thanks for the answer,in the snippet above i don't think i can have collisions or i can?

Comment: If no capacity is specified, [LinkedHashSet has an initial capacity of 16 and load factor of 0.75](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html).  If you go beyond 12, it will expand the capacity further, so as long as you think you will stay under 12, you should see few to no collisions.  Otherwise, you should consider setting the initial capacity as well.

Answer (score 0):

For hashing operations like the `contains()` you have above, the worst case complexity is big O of n. This happens when there are n instances with the same hash value and the hashing implementation is chaining. This also happens when n instances have the same hash-value sequence and the implementation is open-addressing. Both of these cases are unlikely, but nevertheless contains() is big O of (n) and small O of (n) and thus is theta of (n).

In practice, people often care about average running time complexity, and average running time complexity of `contains()` running on a large enough sequence of input is indeed amortized into about constant.